# windbg fail to load symbol with UNC store

Tags: windows, windbg, symbols

I'm debugging a qemu windows machine in docker and the windbg shows the file is missing. Windbg is attached to qemu

```
kd> .sympath
Symbol search path is: srv*
Expanded Symbol search path is: cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
********************Path Validation Summary*************************
Response              Time (ns)          Location
Deferred                                 srv*
// This looks fine
kd> .reload /f
Loading Kernel Symbols
........***WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for win32k.sys
***WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for win32kbase.sys

Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module List
.....
**********Symbol Loading Error Summary*************
Module Name                        Error
kdnet                              The system cannot find the file specified
...

kd> .!sym noisy
kd> .reload /f
SYMSRV :BYINDEX: 0x1EC
C: Debuggers\x64\sym*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
srv2.pdb
BF1C04B01064EB8B6726099CB49581301

SYMSRV: UNC:C:\Debuggers\x64\sym\srv2.pdb\BF1C04B01064EB8B6726099CB49581301 srv2.pdb   - path not found
SYMSRV: UNC:C:\Debuggers\x64\sym\srv2.pdb\BF1C04B01064EB8B6726099CB49581301 srv2.pd_   - path not found
SYMSRV: UNC:C:\Debuggers\x64\sym\srv2.pdb\BF1C04B01064EB8B6726099CB49581301 file.ptr   - path not found
SYMSRV: store https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols - error 0x800c2f05
SYMSRV: RESULT: 0x800C2F05
DBGHELP:srv2.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP:srv2 - no symbols loaded

************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name                    Error
NETIO       The system cannot find the file specified
The SYMSRV client failed to find a file in the UNC store, or there
is an invalid UNC store (an invalid path or the pingme.txt file is
not present in the root directory), or the file is present in the
symbol server exclusion list.
```

I've encountered this problem a few times. Previously, I rebooted the machine and tried to reload a few times. The reload would be OK after certain times. But this time I couldn't reload no matter how many times I tried.

I can see that the reload process does load several pdbs but most of the modules either no symbols or export symbols. .symfix can't solve my problem.
The network is fine in qemu and docker. What might be the problem?

Comment: 1st step would probably be error code 0x800C2F05: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms867216(v=msdn.10).

Comment: I tried to resync the system time with time server. But it showed "No data was available" and couldn't be solved. I deleted the snapshot and it worked. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Glad it worked out, then.